# How to pick rows with higher value only in Hive

Tags: hive, hiveql

I have the following data in Hive (sorted by Count column):

```
ItemX   ItemXX  Count
-----   ------  -----
item1   item11  8
item1   item12  2
item1   item13  1
item2   item21  10
item2   item22  1
item3   item31  9
item3   item32  7
item3   item33  5
```

I need to filter max Count lines only. Like this:

```
item1   item11  8
item2   item21  10
item3   item31  9
```

How can I do this in Hive QL?

Answer (score 3):

Use `row_number()` function:

```
select ItemX, ItemXX, Count
  from
     (
      select ItemX, ItemXX, Count,
             row_number() over(partition by ItemX order by Count desc) rn 
      from table_name 
     )s
where rn=1
```

Comment: Works like a charm:) Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

In common cases (without sorting) you can use these queries:

```
-- 1.
SELECT a.* FROM tbl a 
INNER JOIN (
    SELECT ItemX, MAX(Count) Count 
    FROM tbl 
    GROUP BY ItemX
) b ON a.ItemX = b.ItemX AND a.Count = b.Count;

-- 2.
SELECT a.* FROM tbl a 
LEFT OUTER JOIN tbl b 
    ON a.ItemX = b.ItemX AND a.Count < b.Count 
WHERE b.ItemX  IS NULL;
```

*Note:* Second query can be execute with Hive 2.2.0+ because complex expressions in `ON` clause are not supported before this version (see [Hive wiki](https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/Hive/LanguageManual+Joins#LanguageManualJoins-JoinSyntax)).

Comment: Solution 1. works - thank you so much!. What is b.x in solution 2?

Comment: @alex-arkhipov Should be ItemX, edited :) Alexander, please fix if I'm wrong

Comment: @leftjoin Solution 2 doesn't work. Get error: "FAILED: SemanticException [Error 10017]: Line 3:28 Both left and right aliases encountered in JOIN 'Count'"

Comment: @alex-arkhipov What is your Hive version? Most probably <2.0 Non-equi joins are not supported then in your version.

Comment: @leftjoin thank you! Your fix and note about Hive version are right!

Comment: @leftjoin you are right. I am using HDP sandbox with Hive 1.2.1000.2.6.4.0-91. Thank you so much once again.